# JSON and subJSON

Tags: java, json

I have a small problem with my JSON Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getJSON("https://api.gamerlabs.net/?type=teamspeak3&host=84.200.52.232&port=9989+&query=10011");
}
public static String getJSON(String url) {
    try {
        String genreJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
        JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);
        System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("data"));
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I use this to get a JSON message, but how can I get the `virtualserver_maxclients` (under data->raw->virtualserver_maxclients)?

Comment: Aren't you having a lot more problems? You are missing ` | JSONException` in your `try` `catch` and `IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));` can't work, since you are invoking `toString()` statically on `IOUtils`. (or are you using apache commons?) That is assuming you are using the libraries from `org.json.*`, which you sadly did not clarify.

Comment: I can't comprehend your English. "I use this to become a json message." sounds like you mean "I use `getJson()` to create a JSON message." 'But how can i become the "virtualserver_maxclients"(unter data-> raw-> vritualserver_maxclients)' has me baffled as to what you are asking. Do you mean "How do I retrieve the virtualserver_maxclients from this data?"

Comment: @Luminous I submitted an edit for this, he confuses get with become. As in: "Waiter! When do I become my coffee?!" - "Sorry, never." (typical German mistake, as "become" sounds like "bekommen" in German, which means "get".)

Comment: @showp1984 Ah! Okay that's good. Just the shape the code is in and that last statement turns my brain upside down.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the particular implementation of JSON you're using as a library, you need to do this:

```
// ...
JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);
JSONObject data = genreJsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject raw = data.getJSONObject("raw");
Object virtualserver_maxclients = raw.get("virtualserver_maxclients");
// ...
```

Of course you can also write this in one line but this way it's easier to trace back `NullPointerException`s.

#### German translation in case you couldn't understand that

> Abhängig davon, welche JSON-Bibliothek du wirklich verwendest, musst du das Folgende machen:
>
> ```
> // ...
> JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);
> JSONObject data = genreJsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
> JSONObject raw = data.getJSONObject("raw");
> Object virtualserver_maxclients = raw.get("virtualserver_maxlicnets");
> // ...
> ```
>
> Natürlich kann man das Ganze hier auch in einer Zeile schreiben, allerdings kann man hier eine mögliche `NullPointerException` besser nachverfolgen.